# How to place a delete button icon besides select HTML control using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've following jQuery code:

```
    $(function () {
      $(document).delegate('.products','click',function (e) {

        var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        var no = table_id.match(/\d+/)[0];            
        var first_row = $('#'+table_id).find('tbody tr:first').attr('id');
        var new_select = $('#'+first_row).children('td:first').find('select:first').clone();
        var tbody = $('#' + table_id + ' tbody');
        var n =  $(this).closest('table').find('select.prod_list').length+1;
        new_select.attr('id','product_id_'+no+'_'+n);
        new_select.attr('name', 'product_id_'+no+'['+n+']');

        $('#'+table_id).find('tbody tr:first').children('td:first').append(new_select);
        $('<button style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;margin-top: 6px;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>').appendTo( $(new_select.find('select')) );//Here I'm having an issue in placing the delete icon button
    });
  });
```

You can see that I'm trying to append a delete icon button to a newly added `<select>` but I'm not. Can some one please help me in this regard?  The js Fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/L247t/

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) instead of `.appendTo()`.

```
$('<button style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;margin-top: 6px;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>').inertAfter( $(new_select.find('select')) );
```

Comment: I just updated my answer. What do you mean image though?

Comment: By image I mean delete icon. You can check this fiddle for the output.http://jsfiddle.net/L247t/ No delete icon is getting appeared over there. I want to show delete icon for each newly created select control and upon clicking the icon only respective select control should get delete.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a button inside an select field. That is not possible.
Inside an select field you can only add "options".

You have two things that you can do:

```
// Adding a delete button after the select-field
new_select.after('<button style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;margin-top: 6px;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
```

or

```
// Appending the select field with an delete option
new_select.append('<option value="del">&times;</option>');
```

I've updated your fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/L247t/1/

Comment: Now it says "Delete Row" inside your Select-field. A little bit cleaner :) 

http://jsfiddle.net/L247t/2/

Comment: The first option you suggested is much more natural to me rather than having the a delete option inside the select. Either way your answers solve the problem the OP is having.